# SharePoint people search showing unpredictable results

Tags: search, search-results, people-search

I've a People search page on SharePoint root site, that has search box and search results web part which is pretty straight forward and mostly being used to search people by name.

Recently, I came across a weird scenario where a keyword being searched is matching other managed properties beside name. For example, "Ahmed" is a name of

- An employee "Ahmed Ali"
- A security group "Ahmedabad Campus -SG"
- Various documents (i.e. "Ahmedabad budget report", "ahmed tasks")

Now when this is being searched it is returning people who are the member of "Ahmedabad Campus - SG" and also people who authored any document that has "ahmed" in it.

How can I prevent people search from searching "Members of" and "Authored Documents" fields.